# When using StoreValue, Selenium claims "This element has no value"

Tags: css, selenium

I have the following code, where I need to get the value:

```
<a href="/checkout/cart.jsf">
Items: 
<span class="numberofitems">1</span>
</a>
```

However, when I attempt to point at it using `css=span [class='numberofitems']`, I get the message "The element has no value; is it really a form field?" The element does have a value which I can see in Firebug, but I can't figure out how to properly store this value.

Comment: span is not a form field, it has html or text, no value

Comment: Are you using IDE, Selenium 1, or WebDriver?  If the latter, which language bindings?

Comment: @Barry Can I have the Html with more details? try using anchor tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we go.. every WebElements given below will give better outcome to get the value **'1'**.

```
By.xpath("//a[@href='/checkout/cart.jsf']/span")

By.xpath("//a[text()='Items: ']/span"))

By.xpath("//span[@class='numberofitems']")
```

If they are not working,

1. Check whether the Elements are HIDDEN with help of Firebug.
2. Check whether the classname, 'numberofitems' is repeated.